# Recursive object property in owl

Tags: recursion, rdf, semantics, owl, ontology

Can we model an object property to be recursive in owl? If not is there any work around?

E.g. I want to define workflow as a class in owl. Task and getSubTasks are class and object property in my ontology respectively. I want to model workflow as combination of task and getSubTasks fetched recursively.

Comment: Please provide an example of your data.  The answer may well be "yes", but it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want to declare that **getSubTasks**, or some superproperty of it, is a *transitive* property, which you can do in OWL.

E.g., if you have a class **Task**, a property **hasImmediateSubTask**, and a property **hasSubTask** such that **hasImmediateSubTask** is a sub-property of **hasSubTask**

> hasImmediateSubTask ⊑ hasSubTask

then from:

> hasImmediateSubTask(a,b)
>   hasImmediateSubTask(a,c)

you can *infer* that:

> hasSubTask(a,b)
>   hasSubTask(a,c)

Now, if you make **hasSubTask** be transitive, then from

> hasSubTask(a,b)
>   hasSubTask(b,d)

you can *infer* that:

> hasSubTask(a,d).